# Is there an overload for Html.DropDownList that will show a value from the model as the currently selected item?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Is there an overload for Html.DropDownList that will show a value from the model as the currently selected item?  In my view I insert a model using as using statement

```
 @using SchoolIn.Models
```

Then I access the model like this:

```
        if (Model.Enrollments != null)
        {   
            @Html.DropDownList("searchString", Model.Enrollments.FirstOrDefault().weekDays.Select(s => new SelectListItem { Text = s.ToString(), Value = s.ToString() }))   
        }
```

Here’s the code from my model:

```
 public virtual string classDays { get; set; }
 public string[] weekDays = new string[6]          { "Day", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday" };
 public string[] WeekDays
 {
 get { return weekDays; }
```

When my view loads it presents a dropdown list that I can select from, I select a day and save the selection but when it loads again, I want the previously selected item to be the default selected in the list.  How can I do this?  I would really appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: Where do you save the selection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you should be able to set `Selected` on the appropriate item:

```
@{
    var Items = Model.Enrollments.FirstOrDefault().weekDays.Select(s => 
        new SelectListItem { Text = s.ToString(), Value = s.ToString() 
            Selected = s.ToString().Equals(PreviouslySelectedValue)
        } 
    );
}
@Html.DropDownList("searchString", Items)
```

You could also use `DropDownListFor`, which should set the selected item to the value of the property.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => PreviouslySelectedValue, Items)
```

Comment: Thanks this worked but it now leads to another issue...I have an array of checkboxes in the view and when I put the selected value in one they all have the same value.  Can you help me or point me to a tutorial that might help me with this?  Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to use DropDownListFor rather than DropDownList. Here is a constructor definition from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703462%28v=vs.108%29.aspx).  There are also five more overloads.

```
public static MvcHtmlString DropDownListFor<TModel, TProperty>(
    this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
    Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression,
    IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this Extension Method :

```
public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> SetSelected(this IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList, object selectedValue)
{
    selectList = selectList ?? new List<SelectListItem>();
    if (selectedValue == null)
        return selectList;
    var vlaue = selectedValue.ToString();
    return selectList.BuildList(m => m.Text, m => m.Value, null, m => String.Equals(m.Value, vlaue, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
}
```

Then you may call it in your view like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CategoryId, ((IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["Categories"]).SetSelected(model.CategoryId))
```